# Using jQuery to adjust a parent element's height to match it's visible child's height

Tags: jquery, css, image, resize, height

I've got a slideshow running in a container and need the height of the container to match the visible slide's height. Unfortunately the images are absolutely positioned and there's nothing I can do about it. To deal with that, I'm using a little jQuery magic to take care of the same functionality.

For some reason, my code isn't working. Whenever the `#container` element is resized the function runs and is *supposed* to adjust `#main`'s height to the same value as the visible slide's.

But, uh.. no bueno. Not showing any errors in my console. Thoughts?

http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/2G4ky/3/

Slideshow Plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="main" class="home" role="main">
      <img class="slide" src="http://payload.cargocollective.com/1/0/18788/1279362/452120_800_892531_800.jpg" />
      <img class="slide" src="http://payload.cargocollective.com/1/0/18788/1279362/452125_800_37eba7_800.jpg" />
      <img class="slide" src="http://payload.cargocollective.com/1/0/18788/1279362/452132_800_7dc0b6_800.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    max-width:960px;
}
#main {
    max-width:780px;
    height:520px;
    margin:0 auto 40px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#ccc;
}
#main img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.home').cycle({
    fx:'fade' 
});
$('#container').resize(function(){
      var child_height = $('.slide:visible').height();
      $('#main').css('height', child_height);
});
```

Comment: Two things: you should include the code in the question, to create a permanent record of the problem which can help others in the future. The second thing is you have a bad choice of image - people solve stackoverflow questions as a break while working, and this is not an image I would want other people to see on my monitor.

Comment: And, further to @Andrew's comment: if you're using a plugin *specify*, and *link to*, the plug-in, in your question. It reduces the effort we have to expend to help you.

Comment: @Andrew Shepherd - updated the question with appropriate code. Thanks's for the heads up.

Comment: I'm not sure because it seems too obvious:  shouldn't it be "var child_height = $('.slide:visible').height()"

Comment: @Andrew Shepherd. Wow, sloppy mistake on my part! It should be. However, still doesn't work. Updating above code and JS Fiddle to reflect-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running before or after the slideshows callback, this scales the image as the window resizes. Perfect!

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#main').css('height',$('img.slide:visible').height());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using the plug-in's callback options, particularly the `after`:

```
$('.home').cycle({
    fx:'fade',
    after: function(){
        $('#main').css('height',$(this).outerHeight());
    }
});
```

[Updated JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2G4ky/1/).

References:

- [`cycle()` plug-in's 'callback' documentation/demonstration](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html)

Comment: appreciate the answer.. doesn't achieve what I'm looking for. Instead of adjusting the image's height, I'd like to adjust it's parent, #main, to match it's height. So.. flip-flopped.

Comment: It...doesn't adjust the image's height. `$(this).outerHeight()` retrieves the height of the image, and assigns that height to the `$('#main')` element.

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't realize it before because it adjust at the slides interval. I'm looking for something continuous and instant, which is why I wandered down the road I did.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by 'continuous and instant'? Or explain how this answer doesn't address the problem you're having? Then I can try and address that problem for you.

Comment: Sure David. I'm sorry for being too vague. Your answer does have the desired effect, but only during the turn around of the slide's cycle. If slide A is on and you resize the window to something smaller than the original size, the height of #main remains 520px until slide A cycles out and B cycles in. Upon B's completion in, #main is dropped into the smaller size and it snaps to the smaller size. Instead, I need it to adjust continuously just as the image size does.

Comment: Using the Before callback is a little better, but I'd still prefer it to be independent of the slideshow and continuous. Just as if CSS would act while resizing the container, but without the slide show

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work well:

```
$(window).load(function() {
var imageHeight = $(".image-box img").height();
$(".image-box img").parent().css('height', imageHeight);
});

$(window).resize(function() {
var imageHeight2 = $(".image-box img").height();
$(".image-box img").parent().css('height', imageHeight2);
});
```

Where ".image-box" is the container for your images.

I also added this to my CSS for responsiveness:

```
.image-box img{
max-width: 100%;
height:auto !important;
```

}